# How do you the return column(s) number(s) based on class of said column?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a list of 185 data-frames. I'm trying to edit them so each data frame only shows its numeric columns and also 2 specific, non-numeric ones.

I've had many issues with solving this, so I plan to use a for loop and find the column numbers of all numeric columns, use match to do the same for the two specific ones and then use c() to overwrite the data-frames.

I can pull the column number for the specific ones with

```
match("Device_Name",colnames(DFList$Dataframe))
```

successfully.

However, I cannot figure out how to return the numbers for all integer columns in a data-frame.

I have tried

```
match(is.numeric(colnames(DFList$Dataframe)),colnames(DFList$Dataframe))
```

and

```
match(class == "numeric",colnames(DFList$Dataframe),colnames(DFList$Dataframe))
```

to name a few, but now I am just taking wild stabs in the dark. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: @Onyambu thank you very much! That's perfect. If you put this as the answer, I can give you the credit for your profile's reputation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
which(sapply(DFList$Dataframe,is.numeric))
```